# agged_with(params[:skill]) ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have issue with gem acts-as-taggable-on  in Rails 5 beta 3.

​**project.rb**​:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base       
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'tags/:skill', to: 'projects#index', as: :skill
```

**projects_controller.rb**:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:category] && Category.exists?(params[:category])
      @category = Category.find(params[:category])
      @projects = @category.projects.order("projects.created_at DESC")    
    elsif params[:skill]
      @projects = Project.tagged_with(params[:skill])
    else  
      @projects = Project.all
    end

    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

On line `@projects = Project.tagged_with(params[:skill])` I get the following error:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.beta3/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:8:in
>   `sanitize'

Comment: May be params[:skill] holds an array of skill tags?

Comment: I checked with tagged_with('ios'). same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `tagged_with` is calling `quote_value` internally, which is an `alias_method` for `sanitize`.

`sanitize` expects only one argument, but the `tagged_with` is calling `quote_value` with two arguments, which is causing the issue.

Refer to [acts_as_taggable](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib%2Facts_as_taggable_on%2Ftaggable%2Fcore.rb#L87-L233), [ActiveRecord::Sanitization](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L8-L11) and the 
[commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/268ee64e6362467fc6d2e54df703c620af78f5fb) that introduced this change.

Comment: I checked with tagged_with('ios'). same error. One argument

Comment: It's not what you pass to tagged_with, it's what tagged_with is calling quite_value with internally. Essentially the version of acts_as_taggable you are using is not compatible with rails-5.

Comment: Either you should reach out to the author of the gem for a fix, or search for a gem that is compatible (someone must have forked it and fixed it already), or fork it yourself and fix it or as the last resort monkey patch the issue in your own application.

Comment: I also have this same issue. I have found the issue logged on the gem on Github at https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/741. I'll comment there.

Answer (score 0):

They fixed this. Download from the `master` branch, in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', :github => 'mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on', :branch => 'master'
```