# Rails 4 Search Engine: Multiple Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, rubygems

I'm fairly new to rails and at the moment coding my first app.
 I created a search for the usernames of my users, but since then I've added a tagging system (using 'acts_as_taggable_on' gem), which I now want to implement in the search functionality.

I've tried it several times now, but always got an Argument error (either 0 for 1 or 2 for 1).

That is how you target the user objects with the tag params:

```
# Find users with any of the specified tags:
User.tagged_with(["awesome", "cool"], :any => true, :wild => true)
```

User Model

```
acts_as_ordered_taggable
# Search 
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where(["username LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
  else
    all
  end
end
# Search Tags
def self.searchtags(searchtags)
  if searchtags
    tagged_with(["#{searchtags}"], :any => true, :wild => true)
  else
    none
  end
end
```

Users Controller

```
def index
  @users = User.search(params[:search])
  @tagged_users = User.searchtags(params[:searchtags]
end
```

User Index View

```
= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
    = submit_tag "Search"
= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do
    = text_field_tag :searchtags, params[:searchtags]
    = submit_tag "Search Tags"

- @users.each do |user|
    = image_tag gravatar_for user if user.use_gravatar == true
    = image_tag user.avatar_filename.url if user.use_gravatar == false
    %h2= link_to user.username, user
    %p= link_to "Favorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "favorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
    %p= user.tag_list

- @tagged_users.each do |user|
    = image_tag gravatar_for user if user.use_gravatar == true
    = image_tag user.avatar_filename.url if user.use_gravatar == false
    %h2= link_to user.username, user
    %p= link_to "Favorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "favorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
    %p= user.tag_list
```

Hope someone can help me by finding a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure, but I've seen the same problems here before. The reason was incomatiability of the versions of 'acts_as_taggable_on' gem with the rails version. I wanted to add this as a comment to your post, but unfortunately, it is still not permitted for my account. You may find solutions here [agged_with(params[:skill]) ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029576/agged-withparamsskill-argumenterror-wrong-number-of-arguments-given-2-ex)

Comment: I've got a working solution. Your answer helped me out!

Comment: Weird thing is, though: if I add `elsif searchtags none` to `self.search` the Argument error (0 for 1) appears again...

Comment: I posted this as a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388648/rails-4-error-argumenterror-wrong-number-of-arguments