# Rails 4 Error: ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, arguments

I am pretty new to rails and currently coding my first application. I created a search to search through my Users (either usernames or tags - using acts_as_taggable_on gem). Following error appears:

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#index
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

User Model

```
# Search 
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where(["username LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
  elsif searchtags
    none
  else
    all
  end
end
# Search Tags
def self.searchtags(searchtags)
  if searchtags
    tagged_with(["#{searchtags}"], :any => true, :wild => true)
  else
    none
  end
end
```

User Controller

```
def index
  @users = User.search(params[:search])
  @tagged_users = User.searchtags(params[:searchtags])
end
```

User Index View

```
= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
    = submit_tag "Search"
= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do
    = text_field_tag :searchtags, params[:searchtags]
    = submit_tag "Search Tags"

- @users.each do |user|
    = image_tag gravatar_for user if user.use_gravatar == true
    = image_tag user.avatar_filename.url if user.use_gravatar == false
    %h2= link_to user.username, user
    %p= link_to "Favorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "favorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
    %p= user.tag_list

- @tagged_users.each do |user|
    = image_tag gravatar_for user if user.use_gravatar == true
    = image_tag user.avatar_filename.url if user.use_gravatar == false
    %h2= link_to user.username, user
    %p= link_to "Favorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "favorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
    %p= user.tag_list
```

**IMPORTANT!**
The error only appears with this piece of code:

```
elsif searchtags
  none
```

in the User Model, without it everything works fine. I need it though to prevent duplications.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to make it possible to perform two searches at once? 
If not I would use something like this:

Model:

```
# Search 
def self.search(search=nil)
    # if search is nil this will return all users
    where(["username LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
end
# Search Tags
def self.searchtags(searchtags)
    tagged_with(["#{searchtags}"], :any => true, :wild => true)
end
```

Controller:

```
def index
  if params.has_key?(:searchtags)
     @users = User.searchtags(params[:searchtags])
  else
     @users = User.search(params[:search])
  end
end
```

Remove @tagged_users.each loop from view.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def self.search(search = nil)
  if search
    where(["username LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
  elsif searchtags
    none
  else
    all
  end
end
# Search Tags
def self.searchtags(searchtags = nil)
  if searchtags
    tagged_with(["#{searchtags}"], :any => true, :wild => true)
  else
    none
  end
end
```

Comment: That works, in general. But. I am not able to see `all` elements on page load (without search).

Answer (score 1):

When you say `elsif searchtags` it is actually trying to call the method defined as `self.searchtags`. Since that method requires a `searchtags` argument to be passed in, you are seeing the error.

I'm not sure what you are trying to check so I don't know the correct way to fix it, but I'm guessing that you need to make the `searchtags` argument optional by defining it as `self.searchtags(searchtags = nil)`

Also, you'll need to use `elsif searchtags.present?` since `none` returns a `Relation` object.

Comment: That works, in general. But. I am not able to see all elements on page load (without search).

Comment: @Gugubaight I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @Gugubaight if the issue is that it isn't evaluating to false like you expect it to, you probably need to use `elsif searchtags.present?` since I think `elsif none` evaluates to `true`

Comment: Cause I have two loops, I need a true if smo already searched something and a false if I am on the main Index View without given params. `searchtags` gives me always a false and `searchtags.present?` always a true...

Comment: Problem: I always get the search results but either nothing gets displayed on the first visit of the page (without search) or I get the search results of one loop and everything from the other loop

Comment: @Gugubaight Does it work to use `searchtags.exists?` ?, if it does, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hmmm. it works exactly the same way as `present?` does